# What does the 'graft' command do in a MANIFEST.in file?

Tags: python, flask, manifest, setup.py

I am currently following the tutorial shown on the Flask documentation website [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/packaging/#tutorial-packaging). In step 3, a MANIFEST.in file is created to specify additional files to include in my application's package. It says to include the following in the file:

```
graft flaskr/templates
graft flaskr/static
include flaskr/schema.sql
```

I am having trouble finding out how the MANIFEST.in file works and what its commands do. Is `graft` used for folders and `include` for individual files? Any references to documentation websites would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- From [here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template)

> A **MANIFEST.in** file can be added in a project to define the list of files to include in the distribution built by the sdist command.
>
> When sdist is run, it will look for the MANIFEST.in file and interpret it to generate the MANIFEST file that contains the list of files that will be included in the package.

- And, **graft** means

> graft dir :   include all files under dir

- It is a good idea to read [Distutils tutorial.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial)